# How to redirect firebase api route to external url

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-hosting

In firebase hosting, how do you redirect all api requests from

```
https://<domain>.web.app/api/v1/db/search?query=<something>
```

To:

```
http://<domain>:<port>/v1/db/search?query=<something>
```

I have looked all around the internet and tried many configurations but to no prevail. Here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist/public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "redirects": [
      {
        "source": "/api/**",
        "destination": "http://<domain>:<port>",
        "type": 302
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have looked at server side, and it seems no request has been made at all. Looking into Developer Tools, I only see index.html being returned.

Help?

Comment: Did you add a custom domain in the firebase console?

Comment: Nope I didn't, cause I'm using a ddns service. Adding that into firebase requires me to edit the TXT records of ddns.net, and unfortunately I don't have access to that.

Answer (score -1):

This can be done if you redirect to a Firebase function that then redirects to the desired external URL

```
exports.redirectToExternalURL = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  const domain = functions.config().redirect.domain;
  const port = functions.config().redirect.port;
  res.status(302).redirect(`http://${domain}:${port}${req.originalUrl}`);
});
```